# How to use relative path with my plugins folders?

Tags: plugin-development, directory

Hi i tried for picking all images in a folder so that what ever images user puts in a specified folder inside my plugin i can take and use it in plugin.

I tried the following php functions to pick images or files in folder

```
glob

scandir
```

When i try the above in wordpress framework am getting error  `The system cannot find the file specified.`
when i try in my local server other than wordpress area it is picking files in the specified folder.

```
<?php
foreach(glob('../images/*.png') as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }?>
```

scan method

```
<?php
 foreach(scandir('../images/') as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }?>
```

The above working fine outside the WordPress Framework

Same thing i tried in WordPress for my plugin in my plugin folder and i can't accomplish the task.This is not working.

**Attempt 1**

```
<?php
foreach(glob('../images/*.png') as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }?>
```

i got nothing no error,no warning and no output.

**Attempt 2**

```
<?php
     foreach(scandir('../images/') as $filename){
         echo $filename;
     }?>
```

I got Warning  `Warning: scandir(../images/,../images/): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)`

```
 Warning: scandir(../images/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

The file am trying this is in different folder but same directory.

For example

- Php file with this code is in `inc` folder `inc/settings.php`
- The images am looking is in `images` folder
- Both folder are inside my plugin folder

  ```
   - myplugin
             myplugin.php
             /images
             /inc
             /documentaion
  ```

**Now how to get all images names in my images folder?**

NOTE: I use to include my other php file in my main file like  `include('inc/settings.php');`

These thing works fine so most likely there is no problem in path specifying, May be the problem in  using `scandir` or `glob` function. I can't able to guess.Can anyone help me?

When i simply use the below

```
foreach(glob('images/*.png') as $filename){
         echo $filename;
     }
     ?>
```

**Am getting images from `wp-admin/images` folder any idea?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scandir` and `glob` are related to directory things, so tried with `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` instead of `plugins_url()` which return url but not directory.

Below both function are useful

`WP_PLUGIN_DIR`

```
plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )
```

I tried the above functions it worked well for me.

Remember if you just use

```
<?php
    foreach (glob('images/*.png') as $filename) {
        echo $filename;
    }
?>
```

It will get images from `wp-admin/images` which might be root directory. Am not sure.

Comment if you think anything is wrong here:)

Answer (score 3):

<sub><sup>*This Answer relates to the [first version](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/120647/1) of the Question, and I don't know how to updated it, I'll leave it here as general reference.*</sup></sub>

Don't use a plugin folder (or a theme) for this. Maybe your plugin doesn't have an Upgrade feature and nothing will be overwritten. But the best practice is to use a folder in `/wp-content` root *or* inside `/wp-content/uploads`.

In `/wp-content/my-images`:

```
$test = glob( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/my-images/*.png');
```

In `/wp-content/uploads/my-images`:

```
$up_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$test = glob( $up_dir['basedir'] . '/images/*.png');
```

Comment: Thanks earlier i used to give my predefined images in plugin folder and based on selection i'll use those images in output, there was no problem because i use my naming convention on the dedicated folder. but now i try to give freedom to user like they can place their images in an dedicated folder in my plugin like assets or images.

Comment: so `plugins_url()` worked when i was using my images.am not sure about upgrade option feature in plugin

Comment: I don't understand what's not working for you...

Comment: I use `plugins_url()` navigate to my plugin directory and choose images in previous version.Now how can i get images in a particular folder which is placed inside my plugin?

Comment: I won't know what is the name of the image will be, because its user images.how to pick those images?

Comment: Really, @sun, you should try to add more details to the Question. I'm not following what's the exact problem. If you improve the Q maybe someone else can offer another insight.

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo I Edited my question take a look at it